# Should I use symbol, id=, defs, or some combination thereof in a .svg file?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I am trying to make a [go board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_strategy#mediaviewer/File:Noname_1.png) as a .svg file. I want to define a black stone, a white stone, a horizontal line and a vertical line and then use these to draw a go board with stones.

I would like these elements (and perhaps a few more) to be defined in a separate file (if this is a reasonable thing to do).

Also, how do i call out these different elements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`<use>` elements are allowed to reference other files.  So, for example, it is perfectly valid to do something like:

```
<use xlink:href="my_go_symbols.svg#black-stone" x="100" y="100" />
```

Where the black stone symbol can be a `<symbol>` or, in fact, any SVG element at all.  For example:

```
<circle id="black-stone" fill="black" cx="0" cy="0" r="50" />
```

Comment: thanks, i got the circles to work. having trouble with the lines now.